Facing Issue after upgrading the project to .NET 8.0
I am trying to upgrade my project to .NET 8.0 and I have checked that the required SDK is installed on my machine by the command dotnet --list-sdks.
I also can build solution locally after upgrading my project to .NET 8.0. Now when I am doing Octopus Deploy, the deployment is failing and the error says below:

/root/.dotnet/sdk/3.1.426/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5): error MSB3971: The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v8.0" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK.

I am not sure where else I need to upgrade the framework version or it's related assemblies.

Do you have .net8 Runtime installed ? For app to work on machine runtime should be installed ?

Have you checked the global.json file on your project root folder? It can also contain references to the old version.
